# Datastore namespacing: What is the best approach for constructing these for hierarchical representations?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to efficiently manage the namespaces for a workflow variable management project in the context of using them as Datastore namespaces, implementing protobuf 'package' lineage, etc.  Our project has a concept of variables, some global, some at a job level and some at a task level.

I'm struggling a bit in the most effective way to represent the namespace so that the hierarchy is represented properly. Having the name space be 'deploy' friendly between environments was critical, but easy since the 'environment' makes sense to head up the hierarchy.

Below that, my gut tells me this structure of namespace is well represented and should work, but I'd like other opinions.

```
env_namespace = dev
vars_namespace = dev.ourproject.vars
global_namespace = dev.ourproject.vars.global
job_namespace = dev.ourproject.vars.global.job
task_namespace = dev.ourproject.vars.global.job.task
```

Does the above code appear correct/efficient with a use-case like Datastore?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are solving from your description.  However, it looks like you'll want to use a hierarchy of entities to solve this instead of Datastore namespaces.  E.g. You might have entities keyed like ('Config', env_key), then [('Config', env_key), ('Vars', 'vars')].

Comment: Just like @JimMorrison says, your question is not clear. Can you try explaining again? Namespace is used in datastore to 'virtually' segregate data which belong to different clients (multi-tenant application). I'm struggling to see how that ties into your problem statement. If you want to separate dev from production, you should probably have different instances

Answer (score 0):

Datastore Namespaces are billed by cloud datastore documentation as for usage in multi-tenant applications. What this means in practice is, that you can have no queries spanning more than a single namespace. Also, backup and restore / loading several namespaces into BigQuery and   other things are a general pain to deal with.

While prefix queries can be made to work in google cloud datastore, they do not work  particularly well.

A more conventional way would be to store entities with several fields representing your Information and use different Kinds (tables) to represent your Data.